# Search pages on meta tag keywords in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, search, search-results, metadata

I am not a pro, so the question i am asking could be a candy bar.

I want my pages to be searched by using meta information for the page.

For example if i search *dell* search results should be Hardware.aspx , Laptop.aspx and Computer.aspx

How could i achieve this.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Add dynamically generated META tag to the page. SharePoint will automatically create a crawled property of type Text under in the Web category using the name attribute of the META tag as the crawled property name.

Example:

```
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
public class ProductInformation : WebPart
{
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        // get the model number from query string
        string modelNumber = Page.Request.QueryString["ModelNumber"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelNumber))
        {
            // assign a product category based on the model number
            string productCategory = string.Empty;
            switch (modelNumber)
            {
                case "M300":
                case "M400":
                case "M500":
                case "X200":
                case "X250":
                    productCategory = "Digital Camera";
                    break;
                case "X300":
                case "X358":
                case "X400":
                case "X458":
                case "X500":
                    productCategory = "Digital SLR";
                    break;
            }

            // set the page title
            ContentPlaceHolder contentPlaceHolder = (ContentPlaceHolder)Page.Master.FindControl("PlaceHolderPageTitle");
            contentPlaceHolder.Controls.Clear();
            contentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl() { Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", modelNumber, productCategory) });

            // add the model number and product category to the page as an H2 heading
            Controls.Add(new LiteralControl() { Text = string.Format("<h2>{0} {1}</h2>", modelNumber, productCategory) });

            // generate a META tag
            Page.Header.Controls.Add(new HtmlMeta() { Name = "modelnumber", Content = modelNumber });
        }
    }
}
```

Reference:
http://www.blendmaster.net/blog/2013/01/adding-search-metadata-to-publishing-site-pages-in-sharepoint-2010/

Great article, you will find there more information.